# Lookup values from one data set to another in sas

Tags: sas

```
      Name Country
       A     EU
       B     US
       C     EU
       D     EU
```

I have the above table named myset and I want to add a column a column "Country Code" to it. Th country codes are in the data set named codeset below

```
       Country  Country Code
         EU         001
         US         002
```

My desired output is:

```
        Name       Country       Country Code
         A           EU               001
         B           US               002
         C           EU               001
         D           EU               001
```

Can someone please help me write the code?

Comment: Your question has been answered multiple times, can you validate one of the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search google for sql joins or data merge.

First: Don't use spaces in column names, it makes everything annoying:)
       So rename the column to country_code.

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE joined AS
  SELECT l.Name, l.Country, r.country_code
  FROM tblCountry l
    LEFT JOIN tblCodes r
    ON l.Country = r.Country; 
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PROC SQL` is the fun way to do this:

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE joined AS
  SELECT coun.Name, coun.Country, cod.CountryCode
  FROM Country coun
    LEFT JOIN Codes cod
    ON coun.Country = cod.Country; 
QUIT;
```